# Consistency of Sylvester's Determinant Theorem under Applying Jensen's Inequality

Tags: matrices, determinant, expected-value, jensen-inequality

Sylvester's determinant theorem states that for matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}, B\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$:

\begin{equation}
\det(I_{n}+AB)=\det(I_d+BA)
\end{equation}

In my case I consider $A$ and $B$ to be pos. def., so that by extension I may consider the  $\log\circ\det$ and it is a concave function:

\begin{equation}
\log\circ\det(I_{n}+AB)=\log\circ\det(I_d+BA)
\end{equation}

Because of the concavity I am interested to compute Jensen's inequality (so I need to pass in the expectation). From computer experiments I obtain the following:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\log\circ\det(I_{n}+AB)]&=\mathbb{E}[\log\circ\det(I_d+BA)]\quad\text{($\mathbb{E}$[Sylvester's])}\\
\log\circ\det(I_{n}+\mathbb{E}[AB])&\neq\log\circ\det(I_d+\mathbb{E}[BA])\quad\text{(Why is it not "="?)}
\end{align}

I am not sure why that inequality isn't an equality?

Overall the inequality chain is satisfied:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\log\circ\det(I_{n}+AB)]=\mathbb{E}[\log\circ\det(I_d+BA)]\leq
\log\circ\det(I_{n}+\mathbb{E}[AB])
\end{align}

And

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\log\circ\det(I_{n}+AB)]=\mathbb{E}[\log\circ\det(I_d+BA)]\leq
\log\circ\det(I_{n}+\mathbb{E}[BA])
\end{align}

So that Jensen's inequality is satisfied as expected...

---

**Ultimately I am unsure of why this statement is true:**

\begin{align}
\log\circ\det(I_{n}+\mathbb{E}[AB])&\neq\log\circ\det(I_d+\mathbb{E}[BA])
\end{align}

Could someone offer an explanation for this?

Comment: Actually you have no reason to get the equality because Sylvester's theorem is applied on matrix $AB$ and $BA$ not their esperance a priori. You should try to found a counter example  for non-null bracket: $$ AB-BA\neq 0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one thing: I'm sorry but could you (1) clarify a bit on the term "esperance sa priori" I'm not too familiar with it and (2) So if we are to expand Jensen's inequality do we have any idea which system is preffered to analyze? $AB$ or $BA$?

Comment: Yes, first, I mean, that a priori, the esperance (expectation $\mathbb{E}$) isn't part of Sylvester theorem so there is no reason (a priori) to get a result on the questionned in/equality we are dealing about.

Comment: Secondly, I've no clear idea of example now. But trying to find matrix $A$ and $B$ such $AB-BA\neq0$ is a beginning (no correlated variable is I think necessary)

Comment: Since $AB\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $BA\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ have a different dimension, how is it possible to directly compute their subtraction as such? Unless the subtraction implies an operator looking for some null behaviour? (Don't quite get this part - is that what is meant by your "non-null bracket")

Comment: Indeed you need same dimension. The answer below witnesses that the resul is true so we can't find any countexample as I suggested. Furthermore I was talking about bracket because that substraction is called a bracket but only define with $n=d$. So the solution proposed by @user1551 is clear and simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithmic function and Jensen's inequality are irrelevant. The key issue here is that log-determinant is not an additive function, so that you cannot obtain
$$
\log\det(I+E[AB])=\log\det(I+E[BA])
$$
from the equality
$$
E[\log\det(I+AB)]=E[\log\det(I+BA)].
$$

However, we **do** have $\log\det(I+E[AB])=\log\det(I+E[BA])$ when $A$ and $B$ are sampled from a certain set of symmetric matrices of the same sizes (this is the case when  $n=d$ and $A,B$ are positive definite matrices of the same sizes). This is simply because the determinant of a matrix is equal to the determinant of its transpose:
\begin{aligned}
\log\det(I+E[BA])
&=\log\det\left((I+E[BA])^\top\right)\\
&=\log\det(I+E[(BA)^\top])\\
&=\log\det(I+E[AB]).
\end{aligned}